# В какое событие поместить?

Tags: c#, winforms, сокет

Здравствуй ХешКод!

Вот хочу сделать приложение `WinForm` с использованием сокетов, но возникла проблема. Когда я делал консольное приложение, там был метод `Main`, который постоянно "обновлялся", т.е когда я отправлял данные, то на сервер они сразу же получались. А вот в `WinForm`, тут по-другому. Как тут сделать так, чтобы вот как отправил данные, так сразу-же сервер и получил бы их, в какое событие это поместить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну у вас где-то на сервере должно в отдельном потоке запускаться прослушка точки.

```
private Thread threadListen = null

        private void StartServerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (threadListen == null)
            {
                threadListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenConnected));
                threadListen.IsBackground = true;
                threadListen.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Сервер уже запущен.", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Устанавливает прослушку на подключение клиентов. 
        /// </summary>
        private void ListenConnected()
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            Socket sListen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            sListen.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            sListen.Listen(256);

            while (true)
                {
                    socket = sListen.Accept();
                    byte[] bytesData = new byte[1024];

                    // Получаем данные
                    int bytesRecData = socket.Receive(bytesData);
                    string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesData, 0, bytesRecData);
                    SetTextTerminalSafe(mess);
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Потоко-безопасный метод для вывода текста на терминал.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msg">Текст выводимый на терминал.</param>
        void SetTextTerminalSafe(string msg)
        {
            if (richTextTerminal.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>((message) => richTextTerminal.AppendText("\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | " + message)), msg);
            else
                richTextTerminal.AppendText("\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | " + msg);
        }
```

А клиент отпровляет их сообщение так

```
private void SendMessagesServer()
        {
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 12345);

                Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                server.Connect(ipEndPoint); // Соединяемся с сервером

                server.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Миру мир"));
        }
```